# Move LI's content dynamically with css

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want add all nested li's content(anchor tag) to some dynamic padding-left,

Right now with Css I can add something like this to achieve but this looks like hard coded,

```
.container ul li a {padding-left:1rem}
.container ul ul li a {padding-left:2rem}
.container ul ul ul li a {padding-left:3rem}
.container ul ul ul ul li a {padding-left:4rem}
```

each nested li's .sid class should have 1rem * its nested depth,

I want to add this to N number of nested li's

Can this be done by CSS ? I was thinking only JS is the final solution here ?

```css
ul { list-style: none; padding: 0; margin:0 }
li { margin:0; padding: 0; cursor:pointer}
li a {display: block;}

li a:hover {
  background:green;
}

.container ul li a {padding-left:1rem}
.container ul ul li a {padding-left:2rem}
.container ul ul ul li a {padding-left:3rem}
.container ul ul ul ul li a {padding-left:4rem}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<ul class="parent" id="Head">
    <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>A</span></a></li>
    <li class="item"> 
        <div class="group"><a class="sid"><span>B</span></a> </div>
        <ul class="group-item">
           <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>b</span></a></li>
           <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>b</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <div class="group"><a class="sid"><span>C</span></a></div>
        <ul class="group-item">
          <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>c</span></a></li>
          <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>c</span></a></li>
          <li class="item">
             <div class="group"> <a class="sid"><span>c</span></a> </div>
             <ul class="group-item">
                <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>c1</span></a></li>
                <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>c1</span></a></li>
                <li class="item">
                   <div class="group"> <a class="sid"><span>c1</span></a> </div>
                    <ul class="group-item">
                      <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>c2</span></a></li>
                      <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>c2</span></a></li>
                      <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>c2</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
               </ul>
             </li>
           </ul>
        </li>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This should be your solution.**

I think I understood your question now.
"sid" classes are not related to each other that's why they don't add up. You need to create sub-classes. I hope this is possible in your case otherwise I'd recommend using jQuery.

```css
ul { list-style: none; padding: 0; margin:0 }
li { margin:0; padding: 0; cursor:pointer}
li a {display: block;}

li a:hover {
  background:green;
}

.group-item .sid {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
.sub-group-item .sid {
  padding-left: 2rem;
}
.sub2-group-item .sid {
  padding-left: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<ul class="parent" id="Head">
  <li class="item"><a class="sid"><span>A</span></a></li>
  <li class="item">
      <div class="group"><a class="sid"><span>B</span></a> </div>
      <ul class="group-item">
         <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>b</span></a></li>
         <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>b</span></a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
      <div class="group"><a class="sid"><span>C</span></a></div>
      <ul class="group-item">
        <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>c</span></a></li>
        <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>c</span></a></li>
        <li class="item">
           <div class="group"> <a class="sid"><span>c</span></a> </div>
           <ul class="sub-group-item">
              <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>c1</span></a></li>
              <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>c1</span></a></li>
              <li class="item">
                 <div class="group"> <a class="sid"><span>c1</span></a> </div>
                  <ul class="sub2-group-item">
                    <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>c2</span></a></li>
                    <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>c2</span></a></li>
                    <li class="items"><a class="sid"><span>c2</span></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
             </ul>
           </li>
         </ul>
      </li>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry with this hover functionality will effect, so i want to add padding on anchor tag here not on UL or LI.